# How do I Deploy Astro SSR to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-tools, astrojs

What: 
I am looking to build and deploy an Astro SSR project to Firebase
hosting.

Problem / Issue:

1. Astro requires an adapter to be installed to build. I installed the node adapter; which is definitely not the right thing to do
2. Firebase hosting docs says it supports SSR (next JavaScript) - [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/frameworks-overview#:%7E:text=Support%20during%20this%20early%20preview,full%20server%20rendering%20on%20demand)
3. Have no idea how to deploy SSR. Already have a cloud function to retrieve data from firestore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding on to gil.dev's correct answer, to use Astro with SSR, the `@astrojs/node` adapter is correct choice, but you must use it in [middleware](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/node/#mode) mode.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import node from '@astrojs/node'

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  adapter: node({
    mode: "middleware"
  })
});
```

Comment: Appreciate the details @Austin
I was able to deploy without any issues!

Comment: Which commands are used for deployment? the output: 'server', does not create hosting files, if the output: 'hybrid', then it creates 2 folders "client" and "server"...

Do separate commands need to be executed for deployment? If so, could you kindly list those orders?

If possible, could you please post the configuration for hosting and ssr with commands in steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the deployment command or the right way? I am facing the same problem :(

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a similar answer for the past few days. This isn't documented anywhere specifically for Astro but I followed [the Next.js instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs#initialize_a_new_project) and the app is working. The key parts are:

> `firebase experiments:enable webframeworks`
>
> `firebase init hosting` and answer yes to "Do you want to use a web framework? (experimental)"

Then when you run `firebase deploy` you will see that the build process looks completely different. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @gil.dev - This worked perfectly!
SSR + Cache FTW!

Comment: I'm getting this:

Could not determine the web framework in use.

Error: Unable to detect the web framework in use, check firebase-debug.log for more info.


please help:
I'm trying to convert SSG to SSR in the existing hosting.
in the 'firebase init hosting' step  CLI is asking to select a framework but Astro is not in the list and I've selected Vite and I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Which commands are used for deployment? the output: 'server', does not create hosting files, if the output: 'hybrid', then it creates 2 folders "client" and "server"...

Do separate commands need to be executed for deployment? If so, could you kindly list those orders?

If possible, could you please post the configuration for hosting and ssr with commands in steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/vercel/ for adaptor?