# Not able to convert Astro.js SSG to SSR in firebase existing hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools, astrojs

I'm trying to convert existing astro.js project on firebase hosting from SSG to SSR but I'm getting lots of error.

And I'm using 'Spark' plan. So no cloud functions.

[image]

I've followed: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76704574/5405451)

[image: steps i've taken]

[image]

[image]

When I'm deploying after 'init hosting' without building the astro project with Next.js selected as framework I'm able to see:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the exact error you're getting comes from, but **there is no way to run server-side code on Firebase's free Spark plan**. In order to run any SSR, you will need to be on the paid Blaze plan.